# How to get query created by the prepare statement in PDO

Tags: php, pdo

We can use prepare method to get the query prepared for multiple time use in PDO.

But i want to know that can we see all the queries executed at the DB.
For e.g see below:

```
<?php

    // Cosidering DB connection already set here. With $db.
    // using named placeholder

    $db->prepare("select * from user where id=:id");
    $db->bindParam(':id',$id);

    for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
    {
       $id=$i;
       $db->execute();
    }

?>
```

OK now we can see that this code will run 5 queries.
So how can i get these queries which is executed by this execute() statement???

Hope I am clear to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik, unless you extend the PDO class, I don't think its possible. You possibly can enable a log on your (development) database however. Don't use it in production.